# How to give height and width to div dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What is the best possible way using jQuery to give height and width to parent div of an Image.

```
<div><img src="source.jpg" width="%width" height="%height" /></div>
```

Please note that , there are more than one tags like this. 3-4 images and DIVS.

thanks in advances.

jQuery solution will be preferred.

Comment: How would you approach the problem and how is that approach not delivering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery dimensions.

Add a class to each image:

```
<div><img class='myImage' src="source.jpg" width="%width" height="%height" /></div>
```

js:

```
$(".myImage").each(function(){
  $(this).parent().css( { width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height() } );
});
```

That's it.

Gl